# How to force ssl in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

I am using codeigniter 3. How do I force SSL connection to my web pages so that all the pages are loaded with the green padlock icon beside it?

Note: How can I do this without having to edit htaccess file ?

Comment: constructor for loading the user defined  helper: public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('ssl_helper'));
        force_ssl();
    } And create a helper function with file name ssl_helper.php:  function force_ssl() {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
        $url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
} Also enable helpers in config.php. Otherwise with htaccess the controllers may not work &you can load external icons also

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Open config file from location `application/config/config.php` and enable or set hooks to true like this:

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Then create a new file named `hooks.php` inside the `config` folder (i.e. application/config/hooks.php) and add the following code in it:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'function' => 'redirect_ssl',
    'filename' => 'ssl.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Now create a new directory named `hooks` inside the `application` folder (i.e. application/hooks) and then create a new file named `ssl.php` inside the `hooks` folder (i.e. application/hooks/ssl.php).

Add the following code in the `ssl.php` file:

```
function redirect_ssl() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
    $exclude =  array('client');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
    if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
        // redirecting to ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    } else {
        // redirecting with no ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already trying this. but the ssl still shows not secure. why is that?

Comment: @TriMurvianto check for insecure elements on page source such as images loaded with http, scripts with full path hard coded http instead of https

Comment: where to add the `cert file` and `key file` in codeigniter? And how it will be accessed by c?

Comment: When I run with HTTP the request body is missing

Comment: **This solution work in my case** but make sure that in **config.php** set base url `$config['base_url']='https://example.com'` .

Comment: Work! But, instead using `post_controller_constructor`, I use `pre_controller`.

Answer (score 29):

1. Change `base_url` in your config:

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.my-site.com/';
   ```
2. Provide a certificate for your secure connection
3. Redirect incoming traffic from `http` to `https`:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ```

Comment: This is by far the simplest and best solution IMHO. I had a site that was not behaving when I used my usual htaccess file. Turns out the original author did not explicitly set the base url.

Comment: @fustaki Can you please elaborate step 2. Where to provide certificate in CI.

Comment: @NomanJaved: A certificate is usually setup through your web panel and the webserver (often Apache) will take care of all details; CodeIgniter usually does not have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

**Codeigniter(GAE)**: best practice to redirect http to https in the ssl.php file:

```
function force_ssl() {
    $server=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $uri=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') {
        redirect("https://{$server}{$uri}");
    }
}
```