# Codeigniter 2.x SSL Redirect Loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl, https

I'm working on a pre-existing codeigniter (v2.1.4) application to add https/ssl to it.

I'm working in [webfaction](https://www.webfaction.com/) hosting. Their normal method of ssl setup includes adding a second website record in the host dashboard which redirects http:// to https:// using the .htaccess (let's call this .htaccess_B for clarity's sake) file. This website record only contains this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The original website record which contains the CodeIgniter application contains this .htaccess (.htaccess_A) file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|javascript|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The SSL certificate is installed and configured correctly as per the webhost instructions.  I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625147/how-to-force-ssl-in-codeigniter) method (top answer) but I'm stuck in a redirect loop.

My config variables in config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
```

hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'function' => 'redirect_ssl',
    'filename' => 'ssl.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
    );
```

and my ssl.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function redirect_ssl() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
    $exclude =  array('');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
    if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
        // redirecting to ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    } else {
        // redirecting with no ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
```

`

I've tried several things including renaming the .htaccess file on the original website record (.htaccess_A), adding a base_url with https:// to no avail. I keep getting stuck in a redirect loop

> GET https://mydomainhere.com/ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in chrome
>   console

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try to open a ticket with them. I am not familiar with PHP, but I did a redirect myself for a django site last week at webfaction. Same approach .htaccess file. They checked and sugested it was due to my browser cache. After I cleared cache it worked. They are quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change base_url in your config:

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'https://mydomainhere.com/';
   ```
2. Redirect incoming traffic from http to https:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ```