# forcing Codeigniter HMVC to use SSL

Tags: apache, codeigniter, ssl

I have a website build with Codeigniter HMVC. On my local machine using Wamp it runs like it should.  I want to upload it to my webserver that has an SSL certificate.

No matter what i try, i cant get the website to run on my webserver. I have tried following this :
[How to force ssl in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625147/how-to-force-ssl-in-codeigniter)
But none of the given solutions work in my situation.

my .htaccess file looks like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

in config.php of codeigniter i have :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';
```

my webserver is an ubuntu 16 machine with apache, using an letsencrypt certificate. mod rewrite is enabled, but besides that is a standard configuration.

I have tried redirecting with hooks as mentioned in the link above, but to no avail.  I have also tried various .htaccess file configuration but also no result there.

Is there anyone who has this running on their server?

regards,

sander

Comment: You're using LetsEncrypt. Did you generate the certificate on your own or are you using Certbot? one of the cool things certbot has is that you can have it make the necessary changes to redirect all http/80 traffic to https/443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say,

> my webserver is an ubuntu 16 machine

I assume you are not using a shared server from a hosting provider and so you have complete access to Apache's configuration files.  If that is true then you should not use .htaccess files. Read [THIS](https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/basics/dont-use-htaccess-unless-you-must) and [THIS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/stop-using-htaccess-files-no-really) to learn why.

I also assume you have a set of Apache "sites-available" files that define `<VirtualHost>` configs. It is inside those `<VirtualHost>` blocks where you should be placing the code you currently have in .htaccess.

To redirect all http requests to https try this as the contents of the "default" site in a "sites-available" configuration file e.g. "000-default.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 (.*) https://www.example.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

What this will do is take any http request and immediately redirect to the https: URL. If you are using some other port besides the typical :80, adjust accordingly.

As mentioned, you can do the rewriting in a VirtualHost. Here's an example for the https: config file (maybe named along the lines of "020-example-443.conf")

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/whatever
    ServerAdmin web-boss@example.com

    <Directory /var/www/whatever>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT]
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    # Certificates delivered by certbot - your's maybe elsewhere
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite/privkey.pem

    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With these in place, you won't have to do anything special in CodeIgniter except, as you already do, use the following

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add after `RewriteEngine on`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```