# Migrated website from http to https and now it's broken

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, http, https

I'm doing an internship and they asked me to fix a website that, after migrating from http to https, it's broken.
I'm becoming insane, it's been days and can't get it fixed... I don't know what to do, neither do the sys admins that asked me to fix it. They did other migrations with no problems.

I changed the urls in the code from http to https.

This is the .htaccess they did:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
  #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
  #request to index.php

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

This is what's inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/webpagename.conf

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And this inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/webpagename-le-ssl,conf

They told me they migrated it like this:
Linux command line:

1. certbot -apache
2. /etc/apache2/sites-available/webpagename.conf and wrote those lines.
3. a2ensite webpagename.conf
4. systemctl reload apache2
5. journalctl -xe

Any ideas? Anything else you need to know to be able to check the problem? The webpage it's PHP/Codeigniter.

Comment: what do you mean "broken"?

Comment: We login and it returns to the same page (login form), it doesn't log in neither redirect to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using CodeIgniter3, as seen here [How to force ssl in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625147/how-to-force-ssl-in-codeigniter) and following the documentation https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html :

You will need to enable hooks by adding to config/config.php file :

`$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;`

Then create a new file named hooks.php inside the config folder (i.e. application/config/hooks.php) and add the following code in it:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'function' => 'redirect_ssl',
    'filename' => 'ssl.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Now create a new directory named hooks inside the application folder (i.e. application/hooks) and then create a new file named ssl.php inside the hooks folder (i.e. application/hooks/ssl.php).

Add the following code in the ssl.php file:

```
function redirect_ssl() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
    $exclude =  array();  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
    if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
        // redirecting to ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    } else {
        // redirecting with no ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
```

Additionnaly you can set the base url to https in config/config.php :

`$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.my-site.com/';`

And finally, set the .htaccess file at the root folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Now you can add each rule in .htaccess one by one to check your migration.