# How to redirect to https when user type http in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, https

I need to redirect my url to https when someone write my url on browser. The problem is when I write my website name on browser with https its working fine showing secure lock. But when I am trying to type myurl.com on browser it will redirecting to http not https. I need to type https before my website url on browser to redirect it on secure lock. How can I redirect it into https automatically when someone write my website url. I have done everything change countless time my htacess file but nothing fix this issue.

Thank You

Comment: did you try any of those answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: Try this, this will defintely help in your case - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42625740/8879741

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add http -> https in your CodeIgniter without configuring .htaccess, you can add following in `application/config/config.php` before `$config['base_url']`:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] == 'http') {
    $web_path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    header('Location: https://'.$web_path);
    die;
}
```

This is not a good way to go but can help you until you identify why webserver isn't reading your .htaccess file. What above code does is, it checks if request came for http, if yes, it creates variable `$web_path` with incoming source path and redirect same with https scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is from .htaccess.

Try this -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myurl\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will work as you expected.

This will pass all the possible combinations and redirect to `https://www.myurl.com` -

1. Url without https - (http://www.myurl.com)
2. Url without www - (https://myurl.com)
3. Url without https and www - (myurl.com)

Please try this. Hope this will work. Thanks.